How to check notification as viewed when manager clicks on ref to other form of notification in right top area of user's notification?
In laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 app when user completes some action on frontend Notification is send to any manager :
class UserQuizRequestCompletedByJobSeekerEventListener
{
    protected GetUserQuizRequestContentInterface $getUserQuizRequestContentInterface;

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(GetUserQuizRequestContentInterface $getUserQuizRequestContentInterface)
    {
        $this->getUserQuizRequestContentInterface = $getUserQuizRequestContentInterface;
    }

    public function handle(UserQuizRequestCompletedByJobSeekerEvent $UserQuizRequestCompletedByJobSeekerEvent)
    {
        $userQuizRequest = $UserQuizRequestCompletedByJobSeekerEvent->userQuizRequest;

        $getNotificationContentFromFeedback = app(GetUserQuizRequestAsCompletedByUserContentInterface::class);
        $managers = Manager::get();
        foreach ($managers as $manager) {
            Notification::send($manager, new UserQuizRequestCompletedByJobSeekerEventNotification(
                userQuizRequest: $userQuizRequest,
                manager: $manager->toArray()
            ));

            $content = $getNotificationContentFromFeedback->get(
                userQuizRequest: $userQuizRequest,
                manager: $manager->toArray(),
                valuesArray: [],
                phpEolLineBreaker: true
            );
            $tempUser = User::factory()->make([
                'id' => $manager->id,
                'name' => $manager->name,
                'email' => $manager->email,
            ]);
            \Filament\Notifications\Notification::make() // Notification is send to any manager
                ->title('Quiz completed by user')
                ->body($content)
                ->info()
                ->sendToDatabase(users: [$tempUser]);
        }

    }
}

Sent Notification holds inside info about action and link inside of dashboard part how to open the form. In db field data of notifications table I see :
{"actions":[],"body":"Hi manager name, \n job seeker Alf Cronin at \"Quizzes\" site run \"HTML category\" quiz \"\nCheck Dashboard by url <a href=\"http:\/\/local-quizzes.com\/app\/service-owner\/user-quiz-requests\/39\/edit\"> Editor Reference <\/a>! \n\n. You have received this email as you are manager of \"Quizzes\" \n\nBest Regards,<br>    Support of Quizzes Team","color":null,"duration":"persistent","icon":"heroicon-o-information-circle","iconColor":"info","status":"info","title":"Quiz completed by user","view":"filament-notifications::notification","viewData":[],"format":"filament"}

This href link to the form and I see this notification in right top area of new notifications and that woks ok, but
when manager click of this link this notification  is still in right top area - as manager clicked on href link, but not on "close"
icon. If there is a way to fix it - so when manager click of this link - the notification would diseapper from notifications?

how about using toaster for the notifications?

Dont send the link in the text of the notification, send it as an action https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/notifications/sending-notifications#adding-actions-to-notifications

I usec 3rd version. I do not see relative example with "link ?"  method. Please, point.

@mstdmstd updated the link the version 3.

Do you mean method     ->actions([         Action::make('view')             ->button()             ->url(route('posts.show', $post), shouldOpenInNewTab: true),         Action::make('undo')             ->color('gray')             ->dispatch('undoEditingPost', [$post->id]),     ])  ? Would it help ?
